# Invalid template file install Magento 2.4 XAMPP

Tags: magento2, xampp

I have installed Magento 2.4 on xampp and I have this error:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'D:/xampp/htdocs/magento2/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'require.js'

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid template file: 'D:/xampp/htdocs/magento2/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/templates/page/js/require_js.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'require.js'
<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml() called at [lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:1114]
#2 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}() called at [lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:1118]
#3 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache() called at [lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php:678]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml() called at [lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page.php:251]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render() called at [lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout.php:171]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult() called at [lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:58]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:138]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor.php:153]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor.php:95]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult() called at [lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Http.php:120]
#11 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor.php:23]
#12 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap.php:264]
#13 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:30]
</pre>
```

The solutions found are of no use.

Someone can help?

Comment: Sorry Magento 2.2.4 develop not 2.4

Comment: Have you try with magento default theme? The Issue is show from theme it self.

Comment: Yes. It's on the default. Already resolved. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Solved
Need to change in function:

```
protected function isPathInDirectories($path, $directories) {
     if (!is_array($directories)) {
         $directories = (array)$directories;
     }
     $realPath = $this->fileDriver->getRealPath($path);
     $realPath = str_replace('\\', '/', $realPath); // extra code added
     foreach ($directories as $directory) {
         if (0 === strpos($realPath, $directory)) {
             return true;
         }
     }
     return false; }
```